# Merging Two, Nearly Similar Text Files

Tags: shell, unix, merge

Suppose we have `~/file1`:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

...and `~/file2`:

```
line1
lineNEW
line3
```

Notice that thes two files are nearly identical, except `line2` differs from `lineNEW`.

**Question:** How can I merge these two files to produce one that reads as follows:

```
line1
line2
lineNEW
line3
```

That is, how can I merge the two files so that all unique lines are captured (without overlap) into a third file? Note that the order of the lines doesn't matter (as long as all unique lines are being captured).

Comment: Can't you create a patch file based on a `diff` and then simply delete the removal lines from it before applying it?

Comment: While labeled 'shell' if you are actually running bash, or another shell that supports reading from file descriptors, you can redirect the second file to a separate descriptor and then simply compare the contents line by line. e.g. `while read -r linea; do read -r -u 3 lineb; [ "$a" = "$b" ] ...; done < file1 3<file2`.

Comment: George, while you've done a great job of explaining what your goal is, including sample data and expected output, the other critical component of a StackOverflow question is the attempt that *you* have made to solve the problem yourself. Experts here are happy to help you improve your work, but we're not short-order programmers. Please edit your question and show your attempt so far, so that we can help you improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{
    print
    getline line < second
    if ($0 != line) print line
}' second=file2 file1
```

will do it

Comment: can be golfed down to `awk '1;{getline L<F}$0!=L{print L}' F=file2 file1`

Comment: or `paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' '{print $1; if ($1 != $2) print $2}'`

Comment: Glenn, this is an ∞% improvement over the code in the question. Is it commonplace to encourage bad questions by providing them with answers rather than downvoting or closing them?

Comment: I dunno. I hope people learn from my answers. I like the challenge of solving these puzzles. And sometimes I like to show off ;)

Answer (score 1):

Considered the command below. It is more robust since it also works for files where a new line has been added instead of replaced (see f1 and f2 below).

First, I executed it using your files. I divided the command(s) into two lines so that it fits nicely in the "code block":

```
$ (awk '{ print NR, $0 }' file1; awk '{ print NR, $0 }' file2) |\
sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 | sort | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

It produces your expected output:

```
line1
line2
lineNEW
line3
```

I also used these two extra files to test it:

f1:

```
line1   stuff after a tab
line2 line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

f2:

```
line1   stuff after a tab
lineNEW
line2 line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

Here is the command:

```
$ (awk '{ print NR, $0 }' f1; awk '{ print NR, $0 }' f2) |\
sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 | sort | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

It produces this output:

```
line1   stuff after a tab
line2 line2
lineNEW
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

Comment: This solution fails if line 2 of the second file is the same as line 3 of the first file. Per the question, it appears that only identical lines *at the same position* should be "uniq"ed.

Comment: @ghoti if only identical lines at the same position should be "uniq"ed, you are correct; this solution won't work. However, I am not completely sure that is what is being asked. The last statement in the question is what makes me doubt:  "Note that the order of the lines doesn't matter (as long as all unique lines are being captured)." Maybe he just means the order of the two different lines in the same position, but I wasn't sure. The use of the word "merge" makes me want to agree with you though.

Comment: Another thing that made me doubt is that if only lines at the same position should be "uniq"ed, adding a line breaks the merge from there on.

Answer (score 1):

When you do not care about the order, just sort them:

```
cat ~/file1 ~/file2 | sort -u > ~/file3
```